# How to update the head of a branch when one of its ancestor commits was updated in another branch

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-amend

```
master ---A---B
               \
feature1        C
```

There are two branches like the above. After committed C, I amended revision B using "git commit --amend". Is it possible for revision C to pick up the changes I made to B?

Answer (score 4):

This will replay the changes in c over the commit b:

```
git checkout feature1
git rebase b
```

or:

```
git checkout feature1
git rebase master
```